# Get unique elements from list of lists when the order of the sublists does not matter

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

I have a list of pairs, representing all edges of cluster in a graph. Actually the list is bigger than this. This is just an example.

```
[[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 5], [6, 3], [3, 6]]
```

`[1, 2]` means an edge between nodes 1 and 2, and so does `[2, 1]`.
So, I have some difficulty to eliminate the repeated pairs to count the in-degrees of the cluster.

The output should be like `[[1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 6]]` or `[[2, 1], [3, 5], [6, 3]]`

Answer (score 4):

If order of the pairs' elements is irrelevant, then use `sorted` to normalize pairs. Then, use a `set` to eliminate duplicates.

```
lst = [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 5], [6, 3], [3, 6]

unique_pairs = {tuple(sorted(p)) for p in lst} # {(1, 2), (3, 6), (3, 5)}
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove duplicates whilst preserving order, you can key off a dict:

```
>>> data = [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 5], [6, 3], [3, 6]
>>> list({frozenset(edge): edge for edge in data}.values())
[[2, 1], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Order is preserved overall, and also the order within each pair. In case of dupes, the last pair seen will be the one kept in result. You could keep the first pair by reversed iteration:

```
>>> list({frozenset(edge): edge for edge in reversed(data)}.values())[::-1]
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [6, 3]]
```

If you have an older version of Python (<3.6) where the standard dict is not order-preserving, then do the same using an `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict((frozenset(edge), edge) for edge in data).values())
[[2, 1], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: My only concern with this solution is that since were are talking about a graph here, it is not impossible we encounter a self-loop, in which case it will fail.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. Good call. Maybe frozenset isn't the best sorting mechanism.

Comment: Updated to also handle the case of a self-loop in the graph.

Comment: Not intuitive, python is a new langage to me. am learning. thanks you sir
Actually its a non directed, weighted graph with no self loops

Comment: Could note that simply reversing `data` there would make the first pair being retained...