# How to keep only single copy of sublists with same elements (but in different order) from a bigger list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have  a list

`[[1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -4], [1, -2, 1], [3, -2, 1], [-4, 1, 2]]`

and I want to keep single copy  of the sub lists with exact same elements. i.e remove

`[[3, -2, 1], [-4, 1, 2]]`

and get following list.

`[[1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -4], [1, -2, 1]]`

What could be the fastest way of doing this?

I am newbie, so language may be bad.

Comment: Does the order matter? Do you need to preserve the order of sublists in the big list, or of elements within the sublists?

Comment: Why isn't [-4, 1, 2] not is the output?

Comment: I think it is supposed to be

Comment: Looks like a typo but we had better let O.P. clarify that rather than editing it

Answer (score -1):

If you want a solution that works for all `lists`, not just the one you provided, you can use `set` and `frozenset` to get a `set` of unique `frozenset`s and convert back to lists.

```
l = [[1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -4], [1, -2, 1], [3, -2, 1], [-4, 1, 2]]
unique = set(map(frozenset, l))
```

will give you a set of frozen sets. If you want to convert the elements back into lists you can do

```
unique_l = list(map(list, set(map(frozenset, l))))
```

---

per @wim's points if the sub-lists can contain duplicates

```
kept = {}
for e in l:
    key = tuple(sorted(e))
    if key not in kept:
        kept[key] = e
unique_l = list(kept.values())
```

and if order of the original list and the sublists matter as well you wanting to be keep the first occurrence of the unique sublist.

Comment: Frozenset will fail if there are any duplicate entries in the sublists.

Comment: No, I don't think you got my point.  Consider `[[1,1,2], [1,2,2]]`.

Comment: so the answers given in the question  that you marked as closing this one - including yours - don't work either... because the question is different

Comment: How so - in what way does the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50769590/674039) not work?

Comment: Only if OP does not care about 1. the original order of the sub lists as your constructor will take the later and 2. if to your point that `[[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2]]` should give back `[[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2]]` and not just `[[1,1,2]]` which I think should be the case.

Comment: If you wanted the first element returned rather than last element, it's easy to adapt- you just iterate the input using `reversed`.

Comment: I dont think as values order does not update in dict. It would give `[[1, -2, -4], [1, -2, 1], [1, -2, 3], [-4, 1, 2]]` if `list((ist(OrderedDict((frozenset(edge), edge) for edge in reversed(l)).values()))` - no? (and not reversing the final result is also wrong - correct? Also does not solve number (2)

Comment: I see where you're coming from. But it's not clear from question whether your interpretation or my interpretation is the right one, so I'm waiting for clarification from O.P. on that

Comment: that is fair @wim

Answer (score -2):

if I understand this question very well you want to remove [[3, -2, 1], [-4, 1, 2]] from the main list to get [[1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -4], [1, -2, 1]] and still retain the original list you can simply use this code to copy a list.

```
main_list = [[1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -4], [1, -2, 1], [3, -2, 1], [-4, 1, 2]]
copy_list = main_list[:]
print(copy_list[:-2]) # this is backward indexing. or
print(copy_list[:3]) # This is forward indexing.
print(main_list) # checks if the main list is still intact.....
```

Comment: So this is not generic. What if the main_list was in a different order? This code would have to be modified to find the duplicates.

Answer (score -4):

[A quick way to return list without a specific element in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738700/a-quick-way-to-return-list-without-a-specific-element-in-python)

Example

list_1 = [[1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -4], [1, -2, 1], [3, -2, 1], [-4, 1, 2]]

new_list = list(list_1)

new_list.remove([3, -2, 1], [-4, 1, 2])

if you want to remove by index use the .pop() command

https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-list-clear-pop-remove-del/

Comment: this is not general and just works for this scenario

Comment: seems general to me

Comment: You are just removing by the elements you are not checking if unique

Comment: dude instead of correcting me why don't you help the dude instead and give him the answer. Not everybody is perfect as yourself seems to be.

Comment: So what happens if the numbers are different? For example: [1,2,5] and [5,2,1] your code will assume all of them are 'unique'. With your code, it would need to be modified each time a new number combination is added and that's potentially an infinite number if the list can be longer than 3. That's what 'not generic' means.

Comment: .pop command by index

Comment: and any other way would require a way to tag it or by user input

Comment: ... or just check if its unique @cg4tw.

Comment: or that modesitt.

Comment: The pop command won't work if  test_list = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]... by using remove it's still looking for a specific element and not making sure elements are unique.

Comment: True. I mean honestly, I just gave him a simple answer he said the fastest way. @Rashid 'Lee' Ibrahim

Comment: This has nothing to do with indexes, I wanted the order of sublists don't make any difference while making them unique..