# Remove any duplicates in a list of lists when order doesn't matter (eg. [1,2,3] and [1,3,2] are duplicate sets)?

Tags: python, duplicates, set

I've been deleting all occurrences unintentionally. I would like to keep at least one set of occurrences.

For example, I have `[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[5,6,4]]` and the desired output would be akin to `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`.

```
s = 1,2,3,4,5,6
c = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,6,5]]

remove_sets = []
for a in range(0, len(c)):
    for b in permutations(c[a], 3):
        # my idea is that if list(b) != c[a]
        # it should not delete all occurences.
        if list(b) != c[a]:
            if list(b) in c:
                remove_sets.append(list(b))

# delete those occurences.
for cc in range(0, len(remove_sets)):
    if remove_sets[cc] in c:
        del c[c.index(remove_sets[cc])]
```

**Unintended Result/Output**

```
[[1,2,3]]
```

My desired output would be

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

### Question

Is there a function for removing these duplicate sets where order is switched around?

Comment: I'm sticking to Fixed Three Elements! Perhaps the set comparison would be more efficient. I'm not sure how it would be done!

Comment: Your text and title don't seem to match. Your text seems to want to ignore order but your title says order matters.

Comment: Possible duplicates:  [Get unique elements from list of lists when the order of the sublists does not matter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50769558/674039),  [Efficiently remove duplicates, order-independent, from list of unordered sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57466243/674039)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently remove duplicates, order-independent, from list of unordered sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466243/efficiently-remove-duplicates-order-independent-from-list-of-unordered-sets)

Comment: I went ahead and edited your title to match your example, but feel free to rollback if that's not your intent.

Answer (score 2):

[`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) works if your duplicate sublists are already adjacent and you need to squeeze them into single units:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [next(v) for _, v in groupby(c, sorted)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Caling `sorted` ignores order when grouping, so we can skim the first item from each group to obtain your result.

Otherwise, for the general case, using a dictionary comprehension like

```
>>> list({tuple(sorted(x)): x for x in c}.values())
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 6, 5)]
```

works but it only selects the last-seen item in `c`. If you reverse-iterate `c`, you'll get the first-seen:

```
>>> list({tuple(sorted(x)): x for x in c[::-1]}.values())[::-1]
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Be aware that `sorted` is `O(n(log(n)))`, resulting in an overall complexity of

```
longest_len = max(map(len, c))
O(n * longest_len * log(longest_len))
```

If you need to scale to large inner lists, consider [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of `sorted`.

Comment: Groupby works but is suboptimal.  You should mention that the input `c` needs to be *already* sorted into consecutive groups in order for groupby to work correctly here.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I didn't think about the problem very carefully.

Comment: Updated... the dupe targets are best but I'm surprised they have so few views.